# EMA crossover with supertrend cloud background

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

Below is image of 9-18 EMA crossover code with background color.
i want to change color of background depend on supertrend buy/sell signal.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6eBl.jpg)]

```
//@version=5 
indicator(title='EMA Crossover', overlay=true)

s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9) 
s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)

longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema) 
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

bgcolor(s9ema>s18ema?color.new(color.green,92):s9ema<s18ema?color.new(color.red,92):na)
barcolor(s9ema>s18ema?color.new(color.green,0):s9ema<s18ema?color.new(color.red,0):na)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.green, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small) 
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? Where is your supertrend signal ?

Comment: supertrend signal is still have to add in script

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please show what you tried or reproduce the unexpected behavior you are asking about.